# How to segue with left to right animation and alpha 0 to 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I just want to go to next `ViewController` using `segue` and the next `ViewController` will come from left to right with `alpha 0` at the starting and `1` at the when next `ViewController` is on display.

Here is the code i tried so far without any luck,

```
let transition = CATransition() 
transition.duration = 1.0 
transition.type = kCATransitionPush 
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight 
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
```

Comment: Where is your trial code?

Comment: let transition = CATransition()
                transition.duration = 1.0
                transition.type = kCATransitionPush
                transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
                transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            
                self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
                
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Push" segue for left to write. 
And write an animate in ViewDidload() in SecondVC.

```
self.view1.alpha = 0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
    self.view1.alpha = 1
}
```